# Parameterize method for initializing variables in typescript class

Tags: angular, typescript, initialization, code-reuse, modularity

I have below code in my `constructor` to initialize the variables.

```
public Elements: Observable<dcElementDataStoreItem>;
private elementSubjectData: BehaviorSubject<dcElementDataStoreItem>;

constructor() {
  this.elementSubjectData = new BehaviorSubject([]) as BehaviorSubject<ElementDataStoreItem>;
  this.Elements = this.elementSubjectData.asObservable();
}
```

Now only 2 lines is there, I may have couple of items similar to that.
So can I do something like below code, (but this is not working)

```
constructor() {
  this.initSubjectData<dcElementDataStoreItem>(this.elementSubjectData, this.Elements);
}

private initSubjectData<T>(privateList: BehaviorSubject<T>, publicList: Observable<T>) {
  privateList = new BehaviorSubject([]) as BehaviorSubject<T>;
  publicList = privateList.asObservable();
}
```

So that I can reuse this `initSubjectData` to initialize all other posible methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a field "by reference" as you can do in other languages, but you can pass in the field names instead and access via indexing. Since Typescript supports the concept of a type that is a key of another type, this will be type safe.

```
public elementSubjectData: BehaviorSubject<ElementDataStoreItem>;
public Elements: Observable<ElementDataStoreItem>;
constructor() {
    this.initSubjectData("elementSubjectData", "Elements");
}

private initSubjectData(privateListField: keyof this, publicListField:  keyof this) {
    let privateList =  new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this[privateListField] = new BehaviorSubject([]) as any;
    this[publicListField] = privateList.asObservable() as any;
}
```

There are two problems with this approach:

1. There is no check with regard to field type
2. The properties have to be public in order for the field to be a `keyof` this

We can fix number 1 if we add a second function that returns a typed representation of the field:

```
interface Field<TName, TType> {
    name: string;
    set(value: TType) : void;
}
// In the class
constructor() {
    this.initSubjectData(this.field("elementSubjectData"), this.field("Elements"));
}
field<TKey extends keyof this>(name: TKey): Field<TKey, this[TKey]> {
    return {
        name,
        set: (value) => {
            this[name] = value
        }
    };
}
private initSubjectData<T>(privateListField: Field<keyof this, BehaviorSubject<T>>, publicListField:  Field<keyof this, Observable<T>>) {
    let privateList = new BehaviorSubject([]) as BehaviorSubject<T>;
    privateListField.set(privateList);
    publicListField.set(privateList.asObservable());
}
```